# Efficient "Sequence allignment" comparing two lists of sets to find matches - python

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence

I'm trying to compare two lists of sets (or list of lists), and am struggling with finding an efficient solution.

Given are two lists with different lengths and possibly different size sets at each position. The size of the sets is between 1-6 integers and the size of the lists is approximately 4000 elements for the larger and 100 for the smaller.

```
list_1= [{42, 189, 31}, {32, 75, 189}, {42, 31}, {100, 63}, {75, 37}]
list_2=[{75, 37}, {42, 37}]
```

I then want to find the point in the array where there is the largest overlap between the two lists and count how many elements are in the intersection between each set.

In this case, the best alignment would be at list_1[1:3] where there are two overlapping elements

{32, ***75***, 189} at index 1 of list_1 and ***{75***, 37} at index 0 of list_2 combined with {***42***, 31} at index 2 of list_1 and {***42***, 37} at index 1 of list_2 giving a count 2 because we have two matches. The output arrays should look like this for the above example

```
sequence_alligenment(list_1,list_2): [0,2,0,1]
```

The ordering of the lists is important since that, I am trying to find the point in time where the overlap is the greatest.

I have been trying using the intersection of sets and frozensets without much luck due to some clumsy for-loops surrounding them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very common problem. I  think the most effective would be to just iterate through. It would be the simple to make the code simple. Not the most efective, but i don't see a better solution.

Comment: You can provide a solution then - so far it's more a comment, then proper answer to OP's question ;) brute force solution is also a solution ;)

Comment: The solution .. in my view is just brute force. Simple as that. This solution doesn't have a  better solution giving that the sizes are pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

If you need efficiency (if you need to use this code a lot, and end up waiting on it at times), you could probably use a fuzzy matching algorithm.

Most fuzzy matching algorithms seem to be targetted at strings, but they might be a starting point.

If that's not what you're looking for, you might try doing a reverse index, like:
{42: {42, 189, 31}, 189: {{42, 189, 31}}, 31: {42, 189, 31}, 32: {32, 75, 189}, 75: {32, 75, 189}, 189: {32, 75, 189}, 42: {42, 31}, 31: {42, 31}, 100: {100, 63}, 63: {100, 63}, 75: {75, 37}, 37: {75, 37}}

And then count how many duplicates you get between any two pairs that way.  I believe it'll be O(n) that way.

Answer (score 0):

Look up Smith-Waterman Algorithm. It's a DP algorithm for locally aligning sequences of different lengths.